# Will my app get rejected by apple if i use the following custom localization?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

(Hint: I am just trying to make German as the default language when German or any other language is selected. Incase of French, it will show app in french language but for any othe language , it should show German.)

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSLocale preferredLanguages]);

    NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([language isEqualToString:@"fr"])
    {
        NSArray *langOrder = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:langOrder forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *langOrder = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:langOrder forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    }
```

Comment: You can overwrite language setting for your app. Apple will not reject it.

Answer (score 2):

No, apple will not reject your app.
You can also read the rules for rejection of app from the following link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/

Comment: This is a very general list - if you're very concerned about rejection, it's a good idea to check out the App Store Review Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/. Nobody can definitively say that Apple will or will not reject an app, but I agree here that it's unlikely - none of the rules or restrictions from the guidelines should apply to the OP.